# Is modifying a pre-allocated Python list thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I have a function that dispatches calls to several Redis shards and stores the result in a **pre-allocated** Python list.

Basically, the code goes as follow:

```
def myfunc(calls):
    results = [None] * len(calls)

    for index, (connection, call) in enumerate(calls.iteritems()):
        results[index] = call(connection)

    return results
```

Obviously, as of now this calls the various Redis shards in sequence. I intend to use a thread pool and to make those calls happen in parallel as they can take quite some time.

My question is: given that the `results` list is preallocated and that each calls has a dedicated slot, do I need to **lock it** to put the results from each thread or is there any guarantee that it will work without ?

I will obviously profile the result in the end but I wouldn't want to lock if I don't really need to.

Comment: I believe `some_list[idx] = foo` is threadsafe, yes, since you aren't mutating the list per say, you're just changing a value (e.g. `len(some_list)` doesn't change, the underlying structure is still pointing at the same point in memory, etc). However without some documentation proving that, I'm uncomfortable calling that an answer. "Yeah, sure seems like" is a little iffy for production code.

Comment: I used joblib with threading as a backend, and something of the sort was fine. I'd be more worried about your function returning before all the calls finish, as you don't have a wait of some kind before returning

Comment: @Julius the function return shouldn't hurt anything, but read access might want to wait to ensure the indices are all populated (`a = myfunc([...])` is fine, since `a` will continue to populate after `myfunc` returns)

Comment: @Julius: That is a good point but it's already been taken care of in the real code. I posted a much simplified version to illustrate my question. Thanks for highlighting it though, as it is, in any case, a very important aspect of this design.